# How to resolve the issue with Django 3 that resets the user session when it gets POST data from an external page

Tags: python, django, oauth-2.0

My url path in project's `url.py` is defined as follows:

```
path('endpoint/', views.Endpoint.as_view(), name='get_endpoint'),
```

The `views.py` include the following class to handle this routing:

```
@method_decorator(csrf_exempt, name='dispatch') 
class Endpoint(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        ############ Here I can see the User Session ##########
        if not request.user.is_authenticated:
            return redirect('authentication_router')

        return redirect(
            'https://app.globus.org/file-manager?method=POST&action=%s&cancelurl=%s&folderlimit=1&filelimit=0&label=%s'
            % (
            request.build_absolute_uri(), "/", "To Transfer your Files Select the Folder first!")
        )

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):  # On return from OAuth Page
        ############ Here, User Session return nothing so user is AnonymousUser ##########
        if request.POST.get('folder[0]'):  # A Endpoint folder was selected
            endpoint_path = os.path.join(request.POST.get('path'), request.POST.get('folder[0]'))
        else:
            endpoint_path = request.POST.get('path')     

        profile = request.user.userprofile # request.user does not has userprofile
        profile.endpoint_path = endpoint_path
        profile.save()

        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('authentication_router'))
```

The problem is when the get is called it finds the request.user value as authenticated user but once the redirect from OAUTH page with POST hits the class it loss all request user session and gives error at this line:

```
profile = request.user.userprofile
```

As, `request.user` seems loss its session and has value of `AnonymousUser` even though till `GET` method it is preserving the user's login session values.

My `settings.py` file includes:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    **'django.contrib.sessions',**
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'myapp',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    **'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',**
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

I am testing it in localhost:8000 .Please let me know what I am missing this code. Same code is perfectly working in Django 1.8 and Python 2.7. Recently, I am trying to upgrade it to work with Django 3 and Python 3. Only difference I can see is in `settings.py` in Django 1.8 version includes: `'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',`in `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` which is removed in latest version of Django.